# Getting an error when trying to record in OpenMDAO

Tags: python, openmdao

I am trying to set up, run and record a model. The first section of the code works flawlessly, hence I provided the generalized lines of code for the subsystems, connections, design variables, constraints and objectives I use.

```
import openmdao.api as om

prob = om.Problem()

prob.model.add_subsystem(...)

prob.model.connect(...)

prob.model.add_design_var(...)
prob.model.add_objective(...)
prob.model.add_constraint(...)

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP', tol=1e-9, disp=False)
```

However, if I try to connect the recorder such as:

```
recorder = om.SqliteRecorder('cases.sql')
prob.add_recorder(recorder)

prob.setup()
prob.set_solver_print(0)
prob.run_driver()
prob.record("after_run_driver")

cr = om.CaseReader("cases.sql")
driver_cases = cr.list_cases('problem', out_stream=None)
case = cr.get_case('after_run_driver')

const = case['con1']
print(const)

const_K = case.get_val("con1", units='K')
print(const_K)
```

I get an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\philipp\Anaconda3\envs\Repo Philipp\lib\site-packages\openmdao\recorders\case_reader.py", line 26, in CaseReader
    return SqliteCaseReader(filename, pre_load, metadata_filename)
  File "C:\Users\philipp\Anaconda3\envs\Repo Philipp\lib\site-packages\openmdao\recorders\sqlite_reader.py", line 84, in __init__
    check_valid_sqlite3_db(filename)
  File "C:\Users\philipp\Anaconda3\envs\Repo Philipp\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\record_util.py", line 121, in check_valid_sqlite3_db
    raise IOError('File does not exist({0})'.format(filename))
OSError: File does not exist(cases.sql)
```

Can someone please explain what I am missing? I thought that the *cases.sql* file get created and written to during the execution.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback for the error message.

Comment: Can you verify whether the file exists in the folder/directory where you ran the model?

Comment: What version of OpenMDAO are you using?

Comment: @Rob Falck I'm using version 3.15.0.

Comment: @swryan No, that is my point, it does not exists. As far as I know, it should be created during the run. Even if I initialize an empty file in that directory called 'cases.sql' it throws the same error.

Comment: Could you please try attaching the recorder to the driver, just to see if it makes the file.  Also, just to check, is there any code in your system that might switch the current working directory?

Comment: This may not fix it, but try adding a call to prob.cleanup() before you create the CaseReader to make sure the contents of the db are flushed.

Comment: @Bret Naylor Your suggestion to call pron.cleanup() solved my issue.